# Getting the document and/or field font?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm attempting to detect the font of a loaded PDF, so far I can pull the COSDictionary and see the font, but I can't get to it explicitly.

This is what I had thought would achieve this, and works up until I try to get the string value of the base font:

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load("/paath/document.pdf");
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();  
COSDictionary dic = (COSDictionary) docCatalog.getCOSDictionary();
COSName docFont = (COSName) dic.getDictionaryObject(COSName.BASE_FONT);
System.out.println("Font: " + docFont);
```

If I print the COSDictionary 'dic' I can see the base name in the output, so I know I must be close, but all attempts to work my way towards it or use the available methods like getName or construct a PDFont object and use getBaseFont results in 'null'.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: What does "the font of" a document mean? A document can have multiple fonts - are you saying there's exactly one font in the entire document?  Also, if I'm not mistaken, BaseFont is an attribute of a font, not a document.  I think there's a subdictionary called Font (COSName.FONT) that has the used fonts in it - but I'm guessing a lot.

Comment: I suppose it's the font of individual fields I'm trying to get, I can navigate the Acroform object and retrieve size/coordinates, but I'm not able to determine the font name.